# Excel IF and AND statement to determine time ranve

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Hi am trying to show theatre time either as in-hours or out of hours using the following statement but getting an answer of VALUE.  Can anyone help please?  Anything after 17:00 and before 08:15 out of hours

```
=IF(AND(J2>8:15,J2<17:00),"In hours","Out of Hours")
```

Comment: Amazing thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time to Excel is a double that is formatted to look like time.  By using `8:15` directly in the formula Excel does not know what to do with it.

One can use `"8:15"` and then Excel will convert, but I find it easier to understand to use `TIME()` to dictate an actual time:

```
=IF(AND(J2>TIME(8,15,0),J2<TIME(17,0,0)),"In hours","Out of Hours")
```

Now, if J2 has a date with it, which is an integer with time being the decimal, it will never fall in the inequality.  So we must strip the integer:

```
=IF(AND(MOD(J2,1)>TIME(8,15,0),MOD(J2,1)<TIME(17,0,0)),"In hours","Out of Hours")
```

Comment: Thank you Scott I have used the formula with the date and it works perfectly.  My next question is all of the bank holidays are classed as out of hours for theatres.  I have tested one date with an IF statement below  but it doesn't work.  Can you help with this please as I need to add 10 IF statements to your formula to included all bank holidays between April 23 and March 24.

Comment: New Questions get new posts.  Please post a new question.

Comment: Thank you I will ask a new question.  Do I need to score you anywhere at all please?